# How would I go about binding the HOME key as a tmux prefix?

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to do this in ~/.tmux.conf?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If everything else is configured correctly, it should be as simple as putting this in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g prefix Home
```

Note: Unless you manually “source” your `.tmux.conf`, changes to the file will only take affect when the *tmux* **server** is restarted. Either cleanly exit all your panes, windows (thus closing all your sessions and letting the server exit), or use `tmux kill-server`, then start a fresh session.

This will only work if your terminal emulator is sending an escape sequence that matches the `khome` field of the terminfo database entry for the `TERM` value in effect when you connect to your *tmux* session (i.e. the `TERM` “outside of” *tmux*).

## Generated Escape Sequence for Home

You can verify the escape sequence sent by your terminal emulator by typing the Home key (and a newline) into `cat -v` (you can abort *cat* with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> once it shows you the sequence). Common responses might be `^[[1~` or `^[OH`.

## Expected Escape Sequence for Home

The `TERM` environment variable tells terminfo-based programs (like *tmux*) what escape sequences your terminal emulator (supposedly) understands and generates. The escape sequence generated by the Home key is stored in the `khome` field. You can use *tput* or *infocmp* to extract the field’s value (both use the current `TERM` unless they are given an overriding terminal declaration).

```
tput khome | cat -v ; echo
infocmp -1 | grep -F khome
```

## Fixing a Generated/Expected Mismatch

If the escape sequence generated by your terminal emulator does not match the `khome` entry for your declared `TERM` value, then there are a several things that can be done to try to fix the problem:

1. Reconfigure your terminal emulator.
   This may involve using a different program, picking a different emulation, or just (re)defining the sequence it sends when you press the Home key.
2. Pick a new `TERM` value that is a better match to what your terminal emulator sends and understands.
3. Adjust a terminfo database entry to match your terminal emulation.
   You can use *infocmp* to extract and existing terminfo entry and *tic* to compile your modified entry.
4. Tell *tmux* to adjust its runtime copies of the terminfo database entries.
   *tmux* provides the `terminal-overrides` option that can be used to override individual terminfo fields for various `TERM` values.

For example, if your terminal emulator does not send a sequence for Home, but you can configure one, and the terminfo entry for your `TERM` does not have a `khome` field, then you could 
tell your terminal emulator to send ESC `[` `1` `~`, and use `termname:khome=\033[1~` for your `terminal-overrides` value (where `termname` is a pattern that suitably matches your TERM value).

E.g. in .tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g terminal-overrides "xterm-color:khome=\033[1~"
```

You can use `tmux server-info` to inspect *tmux*’s runtime copies of the terminfo entries.

Note: As above (with the `prefix` change), the easiest way to let this change become effective is to restart your *tmux* server.

Comment: Thanks, that's a ton of helpful info there!

Comment: Could you explain this more thoroughly? cat -v shows that my End key is ^[[F, and tput kend gives me ^[OF

Comment: @RosePerrone: For xterm-style terminals, `^[[F` is the “normal mode” sequence for End, and `^[OF` is the “application mode” sequence for End; switching between these modes is done by control sequences (typically interactive or full screen programs will switch to application mode while they are active). Traditionally, the `kend` entry documents the “application mode” sequence, which is what you see. If a TERM entry has `smkx`, you can use `tput smkx` to switch to ncurses’ “keyboard transmit” mode, which is usually a superset of “application mode”.

Comment: @RosePerrone: This leads to what might be a bug with *tmux*. Specifically, *tmux* switches to “normal mode” when it starts and only switches to “application mode” when it has an active pane that has itself requested that mode. Since *tmux* only recognizes the application mode sequence in `kend`, your active pane will have to be in application mode (so that tmux switches the client’s pane to “application mode”) before *tmux* can recognize a binding for End; i.e. try triggering your End binding after switching your active pane to “application mode” (e.g. `tput smkx`, or start *Vim*).