# In tmux, how do I bind the <End> and <Home> keys to other functions?

Tags: macos, tmux

For example, I want to bind the `<End>` key to be the prefix key in tmux.

This question partially answers my question: [How would I go about binding the HOME key as a tmux prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959433/how-would-i-go-about-binding-the-home-key-as-a-tmux-prefix/7975835#comment21407507_7975835)

I'm using bash on Mac OS 10.8.

I tried to change

```
set -g prefix C-a
```

to

```
set -g prefix End
```

but that didn't work. The result of `tput kend | cat -v ; echo` is `^[OF`, and the result of `cat -v` (and pressing the End key) is `^[[F`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*xterm*-style terminals send two different sequences for each of <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>End</kbd>. In “normal cursor keys” mode, the sequences start with `^[[` (ESC `[`); in “application cursor keys” mode, the sequences start with `^[O` (ESC `O`). The sequence for <kbd>End</kbd> ends with `F`, so it is `^[[F` under “normal cursor keys” mode and `^[OF` under “application cursor keys” mode.

*tmux* 1.8 recognizes both of these sequences by default, so you should not need to do anything special have *tmux* 1.8 reliably recognize xterm-style <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> sequences (i.e. no need for the `terminal-overrides` hack described below).

---

The rest of this post describes a way to get these keys working work *tmux* versions prior to 1.8.

---

Versions of *tmux* prior to 1.8 only recognize <kbd>End</kbd> when sees the sequence provided in the `kend` capability of your attached terminal’s terminfo entry (as specified by TERM when you attach to a *tmux* session). By default, *tmux* switches the client terminal to “normal cursor keys” mode<sup>1</sup>. This ends up meaning that *tmux* will not recognize <kbd>End</kbd> because the terminal sends the “normal cursor keys” sequence but *tmux* only knows about the “application cursor keys” sequence (from `kend`).

Basically, *tmux* seems to expect that <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> are not affected by the cursor key mode. This incompatibility with *xterm*-style terminals results in the key not being recognized properly<sup>2</sup>.

There is a kind of loop-hole here that you can use to verify that this is happening: run `tput smkx` (or start *Emacs* or *Vim*) in your active pane. As long as that pane is active, *tmux* should recognize <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>. This happens because `smkx` sends a sequence to *tmux* that causes it to send `smkx` to the client (which switches the client into “application cursor keys” mode, which sends sequences for <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> that *tmux* will be able to match against the sequences from `khome` and `kend`). This is not a very good workaround, however, because the “application” vs. “normal” state will also be set and reset by interactive or full-screen programs (e.g. *Emacs* and *Vim*) when they start/resume and exit/suspend.

A better workaround would be to use *tmux*’s `terminal-overrides` option to change `kend` (and `khome`) to the “normal” sequences and remove “application cursor keys” changes from `smkx` and `rmkx` (to prevent switching to “application cursor keys” mode, where <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> would send the (now unrecognized) sequences). The arrow keys have special support, so they will always be recognized (assuming *xterm*-style sequences). If you are using `TERM=xterm=256color` to connect to *tmux*, you could do this in your (`~/.tmux.conf`):

```
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm-256color:kend=\E[F:khome=\E[H:smkx=\E=:rmkx=\E>'
```

(Note: because of the way terminfo entries are processed by *tmux* you will need to disconnect all your existing `xterm-256color` clients before the overrides will take effect. Also the values for `smkx` and `rmkx` used above assume that the keypad mode sequence is all that remains once the cursor keys mode sequence has been removed from each.)

Ultimately, this is probably a bug in *tmux*. It should probably either

- include <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> in the special support that the arrow keys get for recognizing both normal mode and application mode sequences, or
- always put the client terminal in “keyboard transmit” mode, and send the appropriate sequence for `TERM=screen` depending on whether the pane has requested normal or application cursor or keypad mode<sup>3</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Actually, it sends the terminfo capability `rmkx` (”end keyboard transmit mode”), which—for `xterm`-like terminfo entries—switches to “normal cursor keys” mode **and** “normal kaypad” mode.
<sup>2</sup> Because the `^[[F` sequence is not recognized as a single key, it ends up being processed as two “key combinations”: `^[[` (ESC `[`, which is treated as `M-[`), and a plain  `F`.
<sup>3</sup> The revision control history indicates that this method (always in keyboard transmit mode, emulate cursor/keypad modes for each pane) was used at one point in the past. I am not clear why it was changed to the current behavior (track keypad mode of the active pane); there may have been some problem with this approach.

Comment: Thanks! What name do I give the kend key in this line in my .tmux.conf? `set -g prefix End` That line didn't work, even though I inserted the `set-option -ga terminal-overrides ...` line before it. What more diagnostic info can I give you?

Comment: @RosePerrone: First, “did’t work” in what way? Did you get an error, or were you simply unable to successfully use End as the prefix? Did the old prefix key still work? (You might want to also use `set -g prefix2 C-b` so you have a backup prefix key.) Second, were you actually originally using `xterm-256color` outside *tmux*? (The `smkx` and `rmkx` values might be different for terminal types; I just guessed at `xterm-256color`.)

Comment: Third, if you run `tmux show -g | grep -F over`, does the reported `terminal-overrides` value include the modification? (The configuration file is only processed when a server is started. So, you need to restart you server (exit all the sessions (so `tmux ls` says `failed to connect to server`) and then start a new one). Alternatively, you could reconfigure your existing server (Prefix `:set -ga …` or `tmux set -ga …`), but you would still need to disconnect any existing clients to make the change effective.

Comment: One time, after I quit tmux, I found that the end key wasn't recoginzed unless I ran `tput smkx` in the window, so I added that to my .bashrc.

Comment: This doesn't always work. What's a better solution? It was working fine yesterday.

Comment: You should not need to send `smkx` manually; it is something that “full screen” tty programs (e.g. *Vim*, *Emacs*, and *tmux*) should send when they start/resume (and `rmxk` when they suspend or exit). Putting it your `.bashrc` is probably inappropriate in most situations. I only described it above as a quick way to demonstrate that Home and End can work. The `terminal-overrides` method is a better approach. I need more information to help diagnose the problem though. What terminal program are you using? What program are you trying to use Home and End with? What are the configurations?

Comment: Using *iTerm 2* 1.0.0.20130302 with a window the running original Default profile (no settings modifications), I can use Home and End in *bash* 3.2.48 (`/bin/bash` from OS X 10.8.2) with no configuration (no `~/.inputrc`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.bash_login`) and `TERM=xterm-256color` to move to the beginning and end of the command line. When I start an instance of the same shell under *tmux* 1.7 with a configuration file that has only the above `terminal-overrides` line from my answer, I can still use Home and End to move on the command line (`TERM=screen` or `screen-256color`).

Comment: It works consistently now! I would also like to use `<C-up>` and `<C-down>` within vim, but they don't work when i'm using tmux. Do you have an answer to this question? stackoverflow.com/questions/15445481/mapping-arrow-keys-when-running-tmux

Comment: I just updated iTerm and found the <End> key is no longer recognized as the tmux prefix. The result of 'tmux show -g | grep -F over` is `terminal-overrides "*88col*:colors=88,*256col*:colors=256,xterm*:XT:Ms=\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\007:Cc=\E]12;%p1%s\007:Cr=\E]112\007:Cs=\E[%p1%d q:Csr=\E[2 q,screen*:XT,xterm-256color:kend=\E[F:khome=\E[H:smkx=\E=:rmkx=\E>"`, and `echo $TERM` gives `xterm-256color`

Comment: I downloaded the old `iTerm` and it still doesn't work. What more diagnostic information can I find?

Comment: I have no idea why it is not working for you. You might try *tmux* 1.8 though: it was changed to recognize the xterm-style sequences from both “cursor key” modes.